Как сделать удаление сообщения, на которое ответили в дискорд на библиотеке Disnake
Я хочу сделать команду для удаления сообщения, на которое ответили этой самой командой. Мне не нужно использовать purge поскольку оно чистит весь чат, а мне нужно сделать удаление конкретного сообщения.
Я пробовал делать при помощи атрибут reference, однако выдавало ошибку.
@bot.slash_command(name='delete_message', description='Для удаления сообщения введите эту команду ответом на сообщение, которое вы хотите удалить.')
async def delete_message(self, ctx):
    db = sqlite3.connect(database)
    c = db.cursor()
    if ctx.message.reference:
        if c.execute("SELECT level FROM users WHERE id = ?",
                     (ctx.author.id, )).fetchone()[0] > 0:
            await ctx.message.channel.delete_messages(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
    else:
        await ctx.response.send_message(f'Вам нужно использовать команду ответом на сообщения для его удаления.')
    db.commit()
    db.close()

Вот ошибка
Ignoring exception in slash command 'delete_message':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1083, in call_param_func
    return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\utils.py", line 567, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Projects\Pups_bot\cogs\Moderation.py", line 254, in delete_message
    if ctx.message.reference:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ApplicationCommandInteraction' object has no attribute 'message'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1378, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\zzz03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 737, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ApplicationCommandInteraction' object has no attribute 'message'



Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ApplicationCommandInteraction' object has no attribute 'message'

Для самого начала хочу подметить, что IDE Вам сразу выдает ошибку, что объект ACI не имеет атрибута message. Если Вы не очень поняли, про что я говорю, то советую немного изучить ООП питона и попрактиковаться в работе с этим. Проверить, какие атрибуты имеет объект можно в документации Disnake
Также в Slash-командах вместо объекта ctx (который используется в текстовых командах) используется inter (interaction), это связанно с тем, что Slash-команды работают через взаимодействия и ctx там банально работать не будет. Но если Вы все-таки сделаете это через обычную текстовую команду, то используйте функцию:
await ctx.message.reference.resolved.delete()
А реализацию подобного конкретно в Slash-команде я не представляю, ибо объект класса такого атрибута не имеет, и в принципе по логике взаимодействовать с message не может.
Также лично от себя советую проверку уровня администратора вынести в отдельную функцию, чтобы множество раз не дублировать её в своих командах
